# Will I damage my heated rear windscreen if I leave it on?

Tags: hvac, heater, window

My 2003 Opel Agila 1.2 does has an old mechanism where you pull out one of the heater controls and the heated rear window comes on, and it does **not** automatically turn off (by design)

Will I damage the elements if I leave them on for an extended period of time?

Comment: Since it is designed that way, I'd think it wouldn't matter if it was on for a long period of time. (This is conjecture). I don't have any empirical evidence to the fact, but would assume a manufacturer who has to deal with warranty claims would not make it so it could go out after long periods of use. If they didn't, they'd be paying for a *lot* of warranty work they wouldn't have needed to otherwise.

Comment: Don't some cars turn the window defrosters off automatically after a certain period of time? I'm pretty sure they do this, so you should be fine.

Comment: Mine doesn't. It stays on for hours after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely.  The window defrosters don't get hot enough to damage anything.